# Joining videos using the command line

Tags: command-line, video, vlc-media-player

I've had a little mishap with the external harddisk and I've had to restore some files.
Now I have a bunch of video fragments that I'd like to join up again.

I can play the fragments using VLC just fine.
So I went here: https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_Merge_and_Transcode_Multiple_Videos/
and followed the instructions.

The commandline for joining 2 files with the same encoding is:

```
vlc c:\file1.avi file2.avi 
  --sout "#gather:std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=all.ts}" 
  --sout-keep
```

However nothing happens; an empty `all.ts` file gets created.

```
 Directory of C:\PROGRA~1\VideoLAN\VLC

all.ts
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  108,900,364,288 bytes free
```

How do I get vlc to actually create a file with data in it?

If I use the transcoding option:

```
vlc -vvv c:\dir24.avi\fil57.avi c:\dir24.avi\fil58.avi
  --sout-keep 
  --sout=#gather:transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=
192,channels=6}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst=out.mpg} 
  --sout-all
```

I get the following error:
[image]

**How do I get vlc to join the two files?**
Note that I do not know the actual encoding of the files.

Comment: Note that `free video joiner`: http://www.softsea.com/download/Free-Video-Joiner.html does the job (it uses ffmpeg internally). But I'd like to see it working with vlc.

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to do this myself.  Your unanswered question helped.  Here's what I did:

```
vlc c:\file1.avi file2.avi 
  --sout "#gather:std{access=file,dst=newFile.avi}" 
  --sout-keep
```

The example on the VLC wiki page you linked is mux-ing .ps into .ts.  I dropped the mux altogether as it wasn't needed in my case.  Then pointed it to a destination (dst=) having proper file extension.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It is. The OP imitated the VLC doc sample command line, which failed. @kevin-l modified that sample command for AVI files, as described, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You must close VLC *before* running your newly merged file!

Windows: An alternative method is to use:- copy /B filename1.avi + filename2.avi resultFile.avi

Comment: Rexa's simple method works with Windows to join two AVI files into one. But the new resulting file only plays the first, not the second. I tried both VLC and WMP. So somehow the AVI envelope must be edited as well, to change the length/time or whatever(?).